# SQL how to get previous dates from a specific date

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, correlated-subquery

how to get previous dates from a specific date e.g

```
Select PreviousDates  from table where RecvDate(check to get all dates back from RecvDate)
```

select all previous dates  from RecvDate ??
I want to sum AmountReceived all from previous date from current location when moved to next row will sum pervious including current location 
hope u understand

```
Select *,Sum(temp.AmountReceived) OVER() as BalanceTillDate from (select AmountReceived , RecvDate,BillNo  from  CampusRecovery 
where CampusRecovery.BillNo = '000' and CampusRecovery.RecvDate < '2015-05-10'
) as temp
```

Comment: You will get more clear and specific answer If you will show the desire query or something more clear :)

Comment: RecvDate column is Datetime or char? if datetime/date/time then less than `<` operator or `-` can be used .. i mean there can be n no. of ways else it'll be tricky and a bad design at the same time.